# Stream Raspberry pi cam to webbrowser

Tags: raspicam, streaming-video, gstreamer, webrtc

I am trying to stream my rpi-camera to my webbrowser. I would like to use webrtc. I have tried using (and modifying) this [GStreamer WebRTC demos](https://github.com/centricular/gstwebrtc-demos) for webrtc using gstreamer. I can successfully stream vp8 to my browser, the issue is that it is taxing on the cpu to take the h264 frames from the camera and convert it to vp8 then send to the browser via webrtc.

I figure, okay, chrome and firefox support h264, so does webrtc, and so does raspivid. When I try passing the stream directly to the webrtcbin it will send it to the browser but with a lot of stuttering or out right artifacts:

[image: This trying to use the videotestsrc element converting it to h264 and sending it to the webrtcbin]

Is there some magic sauce that will allow me to stream the camera to the browser? I am unsure if its an issue with what profile/level the h264 stream is (although this is what I suspect).

I also looked at [webrtc-unidirectional-h264.c](https://github.com/thaytan/gst-rpicamsrc/blob/master/examples/webrtc-unidirectional-h264.c) and see that the profile is constrained-baseline with level 3.0. is there a way I can get the camera to output this or do I always need to convert it? AFAIK raspivid does not do profiles lower than baseline and level lower than 4. Can this be the issue?

I am stuck here anyone care to shed some light.

Comment: Have you had a look at motioneyeos it's a dedicated distro for using your pi as a network camera.

Comment: jsmpg works - there's a ready-made implementation here: https://github.com/waveform80/pistreaming/

Comment: @rohtua yes, I used to use motioneye, its just sad that the framerate is so low. I can get upto 10fps at 640x480 which is much worse than many cameras on the market. AFAIK the pi can stream 1080p with <1sec latency. The only issue I am having is pushing the h264 to the browser properly. Have you had any experience with doing this?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I guess I've been quite lucky. I'm using motioneye on a Pi3b+ I'm recording at 1600x1200 getting 10fps. It took a bit of tweaking particularly with the streaming settings. I record at the above but the streaming I've had to reduce to 75% quality. Apart from some storage issues (recording direct to nas) I can't say I've had many issues with motioneye. Its doing the job for me for now.

Comment: hrmm... jsmpg is interesting, but still no dice on how to present h264 on the browser.  Although this still relies on transcoding, more specifically transcoding at low resolutions.

Comment: @rohtua WOW, I have never seen that framerate at that resolution even on my Pi3b+. Even when directly wired, nothing like it.

Comment: Mines connected via Wi-Fi. I've turned off all the motion detection side of it, that's probably helped some, it's set to continuously record to the sd. My nas has a script setup that moves the previous 15 minutes worth of files off it every 15 minutes. I've set the camera to start a new file every 5 minutes and it let's me record at the above :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the solution mentioned in

https://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/installation/

works well.  Out-of-the box, the video will have a text overlay, but if you give a "contribution" of $15 or so, and email the author, you can get a key that removes the text.  I'm getting low-latency (0.5 sec or so) video at 1280 X 960 @ 30fps from a Model 3B Raspberry pi and the Raspberry pi camera.  The resultant h.264 video stream is directly viewable in CHROME or Firefox.
Note that I'm not doing 2-way video or audio of any kind, although it is supposed to be capable of that. The program has a lot of options.

Comment: Yeah, I have seen this before. Very promising project. I am very curious as to how they did it. Thanks!

Comment: I believe they are capturing the screen buffer and sending it.  One thing that I can say - it works well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my project, it makes your H264 camera viewable in any browser. (or your basic usb camera, if your hw has m2m compatible h264 encoder, like the rpi)
https://github.com/soyersoyer/fmp4streamer